# Code contain error as unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: laravel

I am creating dependent dropdown in which i want stay dropdown value after page reloading. & i found above error in controller file

```
public function get_reason_details(Request $req)
    {
        $reason_detail_id=Session::get('reason_detail_id');

        $html = '';
        $get_product_details = 
                            DB::table("reason_details")->select("reason_details.*")->where('reason_id',$req->reason_id)->get();

        foreach ($get_product_details as $product) {
            $html .= '<option value="'.$product->reason_detail_id.'"'if($reason_detail_id==$product->reason_detail_id){selected="selected"} '>'.$product->reason_detail.'</option>';
        }
        return response()->json(['html' => $html]);
    }
```

Comment: do like that   echo "selected";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing your `if` condition inside a php variable that is why you are getting this error.

To solve this you can write your `if` condition outside K variable and use a `variable` to select the dropdown. For e.g

```
foreach ($get_product_details as $product) {
     $selected = "false";
     if($reason_detail_id==$product->reason_detail_id) {
          $selected="true";
     }

   $html .= '<option  value="'.$product->reason_detail_id.'" selected="'.$selected.'" >'.$product->reason_detail.'</option>';
}
```